# Countifs: Need to count number of cells 12 months prior to given date in a range

Tags: excel, countif

I had a data set, say "ORANGE" from `12/1/2010` to `12/1/2019`.

```
 A        B             C-FIND
1 org   12/01/2016      09/05/2018
2 org   08/05/2017
3 org   01/07/2018
4 org   12/03/2019
5 apple 11/03/2017
6 apple 9/9/2018
```

To find:

Find number of "ORANGES" 12 months prior to the given date, say `09/05/2018(MENTIONED IN CELL C1).

This is what I tried:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12807,"ORANGES",$B$2:$B$12807,"<=" & C1)
```

Comment: it would be helpful to have sample data and what the problem with what you have tried is, exactly

Comment: Given your data what would be the count you expect?

Comment: Please check now, I had posted a sample one.

Answer (score 0):

you need to bracket the dates:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12807,"ORANGES",$B$2:$B$12807,"<=" & C1,$B$2:$B$12807,">=" & DATE(YEAR(C1)-1,MONTH(C1),DAY(C1)))
```